# How I can pull the new code from bitbucket?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am new at coding. My team has sent a "pull request" to my bitbucket repository to merge their code.

I merged the code to the master branch and I ran `git pull` on my local machine. After that, I checked my code and the git repository in my local device is still the same.

How can I get the changes from master to my local device?

Comment: Are you also on your master branch in the correct directory? Do you see any output when you run the pull command? Can you post it here? Are there any errors? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for all @Adrian Mann.. I have restarted everything(terminal, sublime text) and I have tried to pull again. Finally it is working :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the modified `files` in the `pull request` that your team has sent you. 
Verify the same files in your `local machine`. 
You will see the lines added or modified in Green color on `Bitbucket`.

You will see the changes that have been made by your team. As you have already done `git pull`, you will have the changes that your team have made.